# Non-linear, non-constant coefficient, Laplace equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, finite-differences, poissons-equation

I have the original Poisson/Laplace equation:
$ \nabla^2V = 0$,
and I want to break that down (in the context of electrostatics in Physics), using
$V(x,y) = I(x,y)\rho(x,y)$, where $x$, and $y$, are spatial coordinates, and $\rho(x,y)$ is resistivity.

I apply the chain rule and get the new PDE:

$\rho\nabla^2I + I\nabla^2\rho = 0$

I can input a functional form for $\rho(x,y)$ so that I can numerically solve for $I(x,y)$ under these conditions. My method of choice is using finite-differencing because it's the simplest method, and one that I am comfortable implementing.

Is there a well-known PDE that follows this form, and are there analytical solutions to it (e.g. for special cases)? While it doesn't seem impossible for an FD method to handle it, I want to have some sanity checks or assurance that the solution for $I(x,y)$ is unique, given some $\rho(x,y)$.

Any help would be appreciated! For context, it's been a while since my PDE class...

Comment: Applying the chain rule should give $\nabla^2 V=I\nabla^2 \rho + \rho \nabla^2I +2 \nabla I \cdot \nabla \rho$. If $\rho$ is known, why not just solve for $V$ then find $I=V/\rho$?

Comment: Hm, that's a good point - perhaps I was overthinking it and also had a wrong idea in my head regarding how the anisotropy of $\rho$ and $V$ may talk to each other. Anyways, thanks for pointer (and checking my chain rule-ing)! I'll have to have another stab at it.

Comment: No problem. It might be worthwhile considering the validity of your first expression $V=I \rho$. Presuming that $I$ is the (steady state) current in an Ohmic medium with conductivity $\sigma$: we find $\sigma(x) \nabla \cdot E(x) + E(x) \cdot \nabla \sigma(x) =0$, this does reproduce Laplace's equation if $\sigma$ is a constant. If $\sigma$ is spatially dependent, you are left solving what looks like a more tricky PDE. See eg. Zangwill *Electrodynamics* chapter 9 for the discussion.

Comment: That's even more useful! That's going to help me bridge the gap between solid-state and my undergrad E&M. Thanks again for the reference.